# In Fiddler, identify time it took to download a resource (like an image, js, css)

Tags: http, tcp, fiddler

After capturing network traffic in Fiddler while accessing some application via browser, how can I determine the amount of time it took for browser to download a given resource.
For example, the browser is trying to download an image. I can see the usual statistics about Client and Server response time on the GET request, but which metric tells me how long it actually took to download the image itself?

```
ClientConnected:        09:12:32.951
ClientBeginRequest:     09:12:32.951
GotRequestHeaders:      00:00:00.000
ClientDoneRequest:      09:12:32.951
Determine Gateway:      0ms
DNS Lookup:             0ms
TCP/IP Connect:         0ms
HTTPS Handshake:        0ms
ServerConnected:        09:12:32.951
FiddlerBeginRequest:    09:12:32.951
ServerGotRequest:       09:12:32.951
ServerBeginResponse:    09:12:33.123
GotResponseHeaders:     00:00:00.000
ServerDoneResponse:     09:12:33.139
ClientBeginResponse:    09:12:33.139
ClientDoneResponse:     09:12:33.139

Overall Elapsed:        0:00:00.188
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. The time it took is apparently displayed as `Overall Elapsed:    0:00:00.188` -- which means 0.188 second

Comment: Measuring requests that take only milliseconds with Fiddler is a bad idea. A proxy like Fiddler always delays the request/response a bit. Why don't you use the browser integrated development/network measurements available e.g. in Firefox or Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP request is a request irrespective of it's a api call or a http image resource request call. As @Robert mentioned in his comment you should use browser's integrated dev tools to measure such performance metrics.

One more thing you need to understand is typically an html page is composed of multiple resources hence you will see multiple HTTP requests in Fiddler/Integration network tool for the same page. e.g. below can execute in order when you hit a url which gives you HTML

1. Download HTML page
2. once Browser has the HTML page it starts parsing it to render it and wherever it finds a `<img...>` tag it makes another http://yourwebsite.com/image.jpg call and that should appear as a new http request in Fiddler for which you will get same performance stats.

one more thing you should pay attention to is the expiry policy set no resource i.e. typically browser downloads resource first time and after that for a specific period of time they fetch it from cache instead of downloading it again to improve performance so the stats might change next time.